# Ready-to-use kvm server-images for Rails-Apps?

Tags: security, debian, ruby-on-rails, kvm-virtualization, disk-image

I'm taking care of some Rails-Deployments. For this I use several KVM virtual machines like this:

- Apache Load-Balancer (mod_proxy) & HTTPS-Gateway

foreach rails-app
{

- Rails-Server (Apache/Phusion Passenger)
- Fileserver (NFSv4)
- Database-Server (PostgreSQL)

}

as well as:

- Nagios Monitoring
- Ossec Intrusion-Detection

All VMs are Debian squeeze, firewalled with iptables, fetching security-updates automatically, etc. etc. etc.

I want to get this as secure as possible .. and I wonder if there are similar virtual Network-Setups ready-to-use and possibly publicly reviewed somewhere?

If there really aren't I might setup a site with my setup if there is some interest in this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if their approach is for maximum security, but you could have a look at the Bitnami website. They offer VMware images for various software stacks.